# Update a row by another row within one table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

I am using Access 2016 and I have a table with some data missing. I need to Update the missing data based on other rows of the same table. The table has two Identifyer and two Criteria fields and the Null fields represent the missing data. Fortunately, the data is only missing in the Column Criteria2 and when Criteria1 is not NULL:

```
Identifyer1  Identifyer2  Criteria1  Criteria2  
  10             a                     A3        
  10             a           X        NULL     
  20             b                     B3     
  30             c                     C3
  40             d                     D3
  40             d           Y        NULL
```

To fill in the missing data it is sufficient to copy the Criteria2 values of the same Identifyers. So the result should look like this:

```
Identifyer1  Identifyer2  Criteria1  Criteria2  
  10             a                     A3        
  10             a           X         A3     
  20             b                     B3     
  30             c                     C3
  40             d                     D3
  40             d           Y         D3
```

I have tried something like this, but I can't complete the Code:

`Update table1 Set Criteria2 = (`How to copy values here?`) Where Criteria1 is not NULL AND Identifyer1 = Identifyer1 AND Identifyer2 = Identifyer2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since update queries must be [updateable](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html) in MS Access, consider the domain aggregate, `DMax`, which corresponds to a correlated subquery:

```sql
UPDATE table1 t1 
SET Criteria2 = DMax("Criteria2", "table1", 
                     "Criteria1 IS NOT NULL AND Identifyer1 ='" & t1.Identifyer1 & "' 
                      AND Identifyer2 = '" &  t1.Identifyer2 & "'")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Update table1 
Set Criteria2 = (
  select max(criteria2) from table1 t1    
  where t1.identifier1 = table1.identifier1 
     and t1.identifier2 = table1.identifier2 
     and t1.criteria2 is not null
) 
Where Criteria1 is not NULL
```

Comment: This looks good, except that there occus an error that the Access Command need to be updateable.